# Dynamic generation of a specialization class

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

What is the best way to dynamically generate a specialization class given an abstract parent class ?

For example, let's say this is my parent class:

```
public abstract class Parent {

    public Parent(int i) {
      // initialization here ...
    }

    @AnImportantAnnotation("")
    public abstract Object testMethod();
}
```

Then I would like to have a method that receives an abstract class and returns and instance of it, like for example:

```
public class Manager {
    public static <T> T getInstance(Class<T> c) {
        return <"instance of dynamically generated specialization class">;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = getInstance(Parent.class);
    }
}
```

The class of the instance returned by the `getInstance` method, overrides the abstract methods found in the `Parent` class. The code of these generated methods depends on the annotations of their corresponding parent methods.

In addition, the generated class should define the same constructors than its parent. For example, the generated class should be equivalent to:

```
public class Son extends Parent {

    //generated constructor
    public Son(int i) {
        super(i);
    }

    public Object testMethod() {
        // dynamically generated behaviour guided by annotations on the overridden method
        return aReturnValue;
    }
}
```

I would prefer pointers to how to do this only from memory (no read/write of files to disk) and if possible without using external libraries (e.g., Javassist). However, explanations of techniques depending on such libraries are also -highly- appreciated.
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: +1: I'd really like to see an answer using `JavaCompiler` totally from memory (no read/write of files to disk), and that can use an specified `ClassLoader` to search for classes in compilation-time!

Comment: I have just included your comment in the question, @BrunoReis. It is indeed a good observation, thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

With classes, I don't think it is possible without a library such as Javassist, however, if you can use interfaces instead of abstract classes, you can use [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).